# Remove n amount of characters from start and end of varying string R

Tags: r

I have the following example string:

```
x <- "ACCGCGCGCCTTCGCGCGCC"
```

I want to cut 5 (or more) characters from each side, regardless of the characters themselves (cannot use regex, as the characters may vary in my files), ending up with this example:

```
GCGCCTTCGC
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to match 5 characters (`.{5}`) from the beginning (`^`) of the string or (`|`) the same number of characters at the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub('^.{5}|.{5}$', '', x)
#[1] "GCGCCTTCGC"
```

---

Or using `substr`

```
n <- 5
substr(x, n + 1, nchar(x) - n)
#[1] "GCGCCTTCGC"
```